# Is a continuous map from circle to any topological space necessarily a loop?

Tags: general-topology

I understand that the image of the circle has to be connected and compact.

By "loop" I mean the image of the circle is a set X such that there is a surjective continuous function $f: [0, 1] \to X$ such that $f(0) = f(1)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $S^1\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ denote the circle, and suppose that the continuous map from the circle to the topological space $Y$ is $h:S^1\to Y$. Define $g:[0,1]\to S^1$ by $g(x) = (\cos(2\pi x), \sin(2\pi x))$. Then $f:[0,1]\to Y$ defined by $f=h\circ g$ is a continuous map such that

- $f([0,1]) = h(S^1)$ and
- $f(0) = f(1).$